# Why do the following expanded if shorthand statements not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my first attempt to write shorthand if statements however am befuddled by why the expanded versions don't work quite the way I imagined they would.

**Code 1** - Does not work

```
if(document.getElementById == true) {
        alert("The document object model is supported by: " + navigator.appName);   
    }
```

**Code 2** - Does work

```
if(document.getElementById != false) {
            alert("The document object model is supported by: " + navigator.appName);   
        }
```

**Code 3** - The shorthand that does work

```
 if(document.getElementById) {
            alert("The document object model is supported by: " + navigator.appName);   
        }
```

Why is that if I expand the shorthand in 3 to the first code sample not work and why does it work if I have it equal to `!= false`?

Comment: Comparing expressions to boolean constants is a really bad habit.

Comment: @Pointy - So how would you read the expression `if(document.getElementById)` i.e. if (condition == true/somevalue ) then execute code?

Comment: If a function or an expression has a boolean result, there's no need for a comparison - the expression is ready to be used as what you call a "shorthand".  In other words, the expression in the parentheses of an `if` statement will be interpreted as boolean. If you have some expression whose value is a boolean, then you're done. If you want to negate it, just precede it with `!`.

Comment: @Pointy - I haven't come across an expression or function that has a boolean result. What would be examples of boolean results that are not explicitly defined i.e. var text = true?

Comment: Any function that returns `true` or `false`; the result of any relational comparison operator (`==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`. etc).

Comment: @Pointy - Righto. Think I follow what you mean now. If I declare `var text = "Test"; if(text) { execute code}` would have a boolean result. Is that correct?

Comment: No, not really. The important point is that once you've definitely got a real boolean value, there's no reason to use an additional relational (comparison) operator. In that example you just wrote - checking to see if a variable contains a "truthy" value, you **don't** have a boolean value. You can write an `if` test like that, but it involves an implicit conversion to boolean using JavaScripts "truthy" test: that is, the result of the conversion is `true` if "text" is not an empty string, the number 0, or `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy - Sorry for being a n00b but can you give me a real life example of a true boolean value. The only one I can think of is `var text = true`.

Comment: All comparison operators return a boolean value. For example, the expression `12 > 5` returns the boolean `true`. The expression `12 > 15` returns the boolean `false`. In both cases the value of the expression as a whole is the result of the greater-than operator. If you say `var test = 12 > 5` then `test` will be assigned a `true` boolean value.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Ah. So only comparison operators would return "true" boolean values of `true` or `false`. Is that correct?

Comment: The `!` operator also returns a boolean. A variable that holds a boolean would obviously return it. A function call _could_ return a boolean, depending on the function, noting that unlike some other languages the return type of a JS function is not specified so the same function could return a boolean in some circumstances and some other type (a string, say) in other circumstances - I wouldn't generally recommend implementing something like that, but the language certainly allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `if` statement:

```
if(document.getElementById == true) {
```

...doesn't work because `document.getElementById` is a function, which is a type of object, and an object is not equal to `true`.

Your second `if` statement:

```
if(document.getElementById != false) {
```

...doesn't really work - even though you think it does - because (I'm assuming) you've only tested it in a browser where `document.getElementById` is defined in which case, again, `.getElementById` is a function, a type of object, which not equal to `false`. **But**, if `.getElementById` is *not* defined then the if test will effectively be testing if `undefined != false` *which is also* `true`. So that test isn't doing what you think it is.

Your third `if` statement:

```
 if(document.getElementById) {
```

...does work. The reason it works is because JavaScript has the concept of "truthy" and "falsy" expressions. The number 0, the empty string `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, and of course `false` are all "falsy" values. Pretty much everything else, including non-zero numbers, non-empty strings, and *any* objects (including functions) are "truthy". If the expression in the `if` statement is "truthy" then the if block will be executed.

(Finally, there really isn't any need to test whether `document.getElementById` exists - I'd be amazed if you can find a browser that runs JS but doesn't define that method.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `document.getElementById` is an existent function, but is not `true`. Try to `document.write(document.getElementById)` and see the result. It won't evaluate `true` neither `false`.

See in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4EqQW/1/).

You don't have to compare it to a boolean, so the best to do is:

```
if(document.getElementById){
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: I'll bite but if it is neither `true` or `false` why does the second statement work?

Comment: PeanutsMonkey - Your second example seems to work because `document.getElementById` exists and is "truthy", and a truthy value is not equal to `false`. But it doesn't really work properly because if the function is undefined your comparison becomes `undefined != false` which is also `true`. (You can test this by changing it to `if(document.blah != false)`, which will also be `true`.)

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey because a DOM element reference is not equal to the boolean constant `false`

Answer (score 1):

Code 1 is truthy but not true.  getElementById is an object but it is not a boolean so comparing it to one will be false.

Here is a blog that explains the concept of truthiness and falsyness:  http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: _"it is not a boolean so comparing it to one will be falsey"_ - the result of the `document.getElementById == true` comparison will actually be the boolean `false` (not just falsey). It's only the `document.getElementById` part that will be truthy or falsey.

Comment: @marteljn - What role do the coercion equality and strict equality operator to the statements I have in my post?

Comment: Your right it doesn't directly apply.  I included it because it helped me undertstand JS comparisons, will remove in order to not confuse anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The first does not work because typeof `document.getElementById` is 'function' and its values is native code, not a boolean "true".

Re. your 3rd example, also try this instead:

```
if (!!document.getElementById) ...
```

The `!!` will force boolean type on the result.

Comment: That `!!` method is unnecessary in an `if` test because `document.getElementById` will be truthy or falsey - the OP already said that that third example works; the question is why does the first one _not_ work...

Comment: It is actually necessary. Try `if (Foo) console.log('Foo')` and it will log "ReferenceError: Foo is not defined"

Comment: It's not necessary if you already know that `document` is defined and you want to test whether it has a method `.getElementById`. Or more generally if you know that `someObject` is defined and you're testing for `someObject.someMethod`. Testing a variable is not the same thing as testing a property of an object...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from the ECMAScript spec:

Look at the procedure for evaluating [`if` statements](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.5): in step 3, the procedure calls [`ToBoolean`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2), which casts objects to the value `true`.  The `ToBoolean` function is where we get the notion of "truthy" and "falsy" values; they are values that are cast by `ToBoolean` into `true` and `false`, respectively.

Now look at the [Abstract Equality Comparison Operation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3) which is used for the `==` operator.  The procedure flow for `Object == boolean` is much more complicated than a simple call to `ToBoolean`.  It goes like this:

```
For some comparison x == y...

1.  If Type(x) is different from Type(y), go to step 14.
19. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

(Go back to step 1, with the boolean cast to a Number by ToNumber[1], then...)

21. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return
    the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x)== y.

(ToPrimative[2] calls the object's toString method; now compare String == Number)

17. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the
    comparison ToNumber(x)== y.

(ToNumber turns the string "function()..." into NaN. Finally...)

5. If x is NaN, return false
```

**Further references:**

[1] [ToNumber](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3)

[2] [ToPrimative](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.1) which calls [[[DefaultValue]]](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2.6), which is a quite a long one.  Fortunately, it resolves quickly in this case, on step 2.